Calculating the torque of multiple nuts
I need to press hockey puck scr to a certain force, so I must hold it between two plates and by bolting plates apply that specific force to the hockey puck. I am using the torque wrench and 8 bolts, so now my question is once I calculate the total torque, T=KFd, to set my torque wrench for each single bolt should I divide the total bolt by my number of bolts so T/8?

Roughly, yes, although the need to retain each screw vs coming loose could potentially introduce a practical lower limit, depending on screw size.
